# how to get power of any number using javascript in recursion logic?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make `power` function using `recursion` .my function is working fine and giving correct output .

but this function  is not optimized  I am calling this function `getPower(num, power / 2)` two times .can we optimized this function

```
function getPower(num, power) {
  if (power === 1) return num;
  if (power % 2 === 0) {
    return getPower(num, power / 2) * getPower(num, power / 2);
  } else {
    return (
      num * getPower(num, (power - 1) / 2) * getPower(num, (power - 1) / 2)
    );
  }
}

console.log(getPower(2, 5));
```

can we store `getPower(num, power / 2)` this value anywhere ? so that I will not call again

Comment: Have a look here https://javascript.info/recursion

Comment: simply cache the result of `getPower(num, power / 2);`, where is the problem?

Comment: @LuísRamalho here is it is not optimised as it take `O(n)` iteration

Comment: @appleapple where I will catch the result (where in function)

Comment: you can cache it anyway you want, this iteration only or whole program life long, which do you want?

Comment: got it thanks for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take a temporary variable for the half value.

```js
function getPower(num, power) {
    var half;
    if (power === 1) return num;
    if (power % 2 === 0) {
        half = getPower(num, power / 2);
        return half * half;
    }
    half = getPower(num, (power - 1) / 2)
    return num * half * half;
}

console.log(getPower(2, 5));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this where you would decrement the power:

```js
function getPower(num, power) {
    if(power === 1) {
        return num
    } else {
        return num * getPower(num, power - 1)
    }
}

console.log(getPower(2, 3)) // 8
```

Comment: @LuísRamalho here is it is not optimised as it take `O(n)` iteration

Comment: I didn't post this :) but you're right, sorry I didn't realize you were looking for something optimized when I shared the javascript.info link

Comment: @RahulChoudary I must have read wrong! I didn't realize you were looking for better time complexity.